# Error writing to an existing xlsm file using OPENPYXL -> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 42, column 8

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl, xlsm

I want to write / change a value to a single cell of an existing xlsm file (let's call it filename.xlsm), maintaining all macros and properties of the original xlsm file.

filename.xlsm has several sheets. I wish to write the value 4 in cell E3 of sheet 'Sup'.

I get the error *"xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 42, column 8"*

The PYTHON code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

InputExcelfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsm', keep_vba=True)

sup_sheet = InputExcelfile['Sup']

sup_sheet['E3'] = 4

InputExcelfile.save('filename.xlsm')
```

I have tried deleting several sheets to see if the error disappears, but this only happens with this sheet.

After running the program and getting the error, I try accessing the Excel and get the error:

[Excel error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8qnR.png)

Help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: The exception tells you that the worksheet contains invalid XML. If openpyxl can't read the file, it can't create one.

Comment: @CharlieClark, thanks for your feedback. Just to be clear. From what you say, even though load_workbook ran ok, there is still a problem reading the file. Could this be because the excel is in Office 365?

Comment: You're asking questions which I can't answer without more information.

Comment: @CharlieClark, I appreciate your help and feedback anyways. Unfortunately I cannot share the Excel due to confidentiality reasons. Many thanks.